# High CPU usage for WindowServer process in Activity monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, activity-monitor

On my Macbook Pro 13" 2020 model, WindowServer is constantly eating away 20% to 40% CPU.

Tried the usual recommendations, but none help. (reduce transparency, display scaling etc)
Also tried to disable True tone for example.
It happens both with a 4K display attached, or standalone on the laptop.

When I streamed the log (log stream  --predicate '(process == "WindowServer")' --debug),
I see tens of messages per second showing:

```
WindowServer: (CoreDisplay) [com.apple.CoreDisplay:default] [DEBUG] - On display 0x78c92091, surface is not detached, CoreDisplay is detached (0x00000000), DetachCode = 0
```

Anyone has some ideas what this is all about?

Comment: I also see the exact same log as yours. Have you found any solution?

Comment: No I didn't. But lately I don't see the extremely high CPU anymore. And I didn't fix it :)  macOS update perhaps?

Comment: I was suffering from the same issue on my 2014 MacBook after upgrading to Big Sur (from High Sierra, upgraded from Mavericks over the years). Don't know about the logs, though. I finally got fed up with it and decided to do a clean install, wiping everything and restoring just what I need from backup. Aside from clearing out all the cruft that accumulated on my SSD, the WindowServer issue is gone. Recommended, if you can spare the time for a clean install!

Comment: Update: while my MacBook does feel more responsive and the battery lasts longer since the clean install, WindowServer CPU usage still jumps to 25% when just moving the mouse pointer. Based on the number of reports I've found, I believe this is a bug in Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

There are reports of Google Chrome causing unexplained high CPU usage in WindowServer: https://chromeisbad.com. Note that Chrome doesn't even need to be running to have this effect. It's the Keystone updater that comes bundled with Chrome causing the high CPU usage.

Completely [removing Chrome](https://chromeisbad.com/#delete) from your system might fix the problem:

> 1. Go to your /Applications folder and drag Chrome to the Trash.
> 2. In the Finder click the Go menu (at the top of the screen), then click "Go to Folder...".
> 3. Type in /Library and hit enter.
>
>    - Check the following folders: LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, Application Support, Caches, Preferences.
>    - Delete all the Google folders, and anything else that starts with com.google... and com.google.keystone...
> 4. Go to "Go to Folder..." again.
> 5. Type in ~/Library and hit enter. (Note the "~")
>
>    - Check the following folders: LaunchAgents, Application Support, Caches, Preferences.
>    - Delete all the Google folders, and anything else that starts with com.google... and com.google.keystone...
> 6. Empty the Trash, and restart your computer.